# How to fill struts jsp text box out of string array data

Tags: java, jsp, struts1

JSP Code:

```
 <td><html:text   maxlength="52" name="MasterBean" property="names"  /> </td>
 <td><html:text   maxlength="52" name="MasterBean" property="names"  /> </td>
 <td><html:text   maxlength="52" name="MasterBean" property="names"  /> </td>
 <td><html:text   maxlength="52" name="MasterBean" property="names"  /> </td>
```

In Bean I have getter setter methods.

```
public String[] getNames() {
    return names;
}

public void setNames(String[] names) {
    this.names = names;
}
```

In the action class the bean gets populated correctly. But the values which are displayed in text boxes doesn't make any sens.

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@42a0b130
[Ljava.lang.String;@42a0b130
[Ljava.lang.String;@42a0b130
[Ljava.lang.String;@42a0b130
```

Persisting part is fine. But displaying what's being persisted is not working.
Any Idea?

I'm Using Struts1

Comment: you are able to print array Reference So apply For Loop  and find each element and then set value into Text Field ID

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [indexed properties](http://www.jajakarta.org/struts/struts1.2/documentation/ja/target/faqs/indexedprops.html). What you see is the string representation of your array (always the same object).
You need to do some indexing like this

```
<td><html:text   maxlength="52" name="MasterBean" property="names[index]"  /> </td>
```